# iPhone UINavigationController bar buttons not showing

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, tableview, navigationcontroller

I am having an issue: I have a tab-bar based app. In MainWindow.xib for the tab that shows the nav controller it links to RootViewController.xib.
in RootViewController.xib I have created a navigation controller and have added a table view.
in RootViewController in viewDidLoad i have **[self.view addSubview:navController.view];**.
The tableview and navigation controller work well for navigation. pressing a cell pushes the controller, and bar buttons work in the pushed controller.
But when I use **self.navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;** nothing shows up at all. also changing **self.navController.navigationItem** to **self..navigationItem** ect.. doesn't help. What do you think the problem could be? I appreciate every answer.
fyi the barbuttonitem is setup with:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Help" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(help)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to use both controller navigation and tab bar controller the u check the sample code of apple documentation. In which both function are use so i given link below.

[UIcatalogue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you init the navigation controller with...

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Then you can set button with...

```
rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton;
```